# Universal power adapter for Europe grounded

Tags: compatibility, power, durability

I am looking to buy a 220v 10a Universal power adapter for Europe (Schuko type) i.e. something like this:
[image: Universal power adapter for Europe]

---

The problem is that the majority of those, do not have the ground pin connected even if they advertise it as grounded:[image: not grounded]

---

or they just can't hold 10a:[image: burned]

So my question is: Where can I find a proper plug adapter?

Answer (score 1):

I would look at Skross products.

They they offer a wide choice of country travel adapters:
https://www.skross.com/en/products/country-travel-adapters
and they seem well aware of the need for grounding.
They have adapters designed to support energy-intensive appliance like drillers.

Their assortment also includes truly universal (worldwide) adapters for globetrotters.